# XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'...in localhost?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting this error.

The exact error is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Documents/item.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I read this error is due to accessing files from different domains.

I want to load one html page (item.html) in a div inside index.html.

Both files are located in the Documents folder. They don't work in localhost but they work when i upload the folder on my hosting.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Thats not localhost its your file system,you can try using firefox it wouldn't give you Access-Control-Allow-Origin error for files in the same directory.

Comment: For some reason it's not working correctly in firefox either.
It works fine when i upload it on my hosting, but on my HDD - no o.O.

Comment: install a server on your local machine instead of opening files directly. Quite simple with node.js or xampp for php so you can run local code from `localhost` domain

Comment: @charlietfl Can i install xampp? Will it work or do i need to install node.js?

Comment: either will work and if both installed the run completely independent of each other

Answer (score 2):

It seems to not be recognizing the request is coming from the same filesystem. In PHP, I would add this to the file being requested. You can do similar things in other languages.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: This is not on a server so you cant set headers

Comment: +1 @lincb Within WordPress when developing locally with WAMP I added this to the top of wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and it solved my local CORS issue.